# Blender 3.4 geometry nodes: multiple outputs

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to instance multiple objects using a "geometry nodes" modifier:

[image: Here is my setup]

obviously, it doesn't work. As you can see, there are two geometries in output. I would like to instance a copy of both of them(as separate geometries). Is there any way to do this(maybe, using Python)?